# jQuery mobile popup width issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How to set the width of popup in % ? I have tried giving width:80% of the popup div. It works fine in a desktop browser, but in mobile browser it squezees automatically.

here is the markup :

```
<div data-role="popup" style="width:80%;left:auto !important;right:0 !important;" id="help-dialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a"   data-dismissible="false" data-transition="none">
```

here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vds2U/61/

When changing jQuery Mobile CSS you need to be careful, specially when working with percentages. Only during **pageshow** event we can calculate correct page dimensions, ipso facto only at this point we can set percentage values to inner page content.

Problem with mobile devices is their sluggishness, it takes time for pageshow event to trigger.

So best course of action requires programatically solution:

#### HTML :

Some dummy popup:

```
<div data-role="popup"id="help-dialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" data-transition="none" data-position-to="window">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Popup</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Focused Field</h3>

        <p>
            <input type="text" id="popup_input" />
        </p> <a href="#" data-role="button"data-rel="back">Close</a>

    </div>                    
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var content_width = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible").outerWidth();
    $('#help-dialog').css({'width':content_width*0.8});
});
```

For this solution to work, it **MUST** be executed during **pageshow** event. This solution also works on mobile devices.

One last thing, use **data-position-to="window"** attribute in your popup <div> if you want it centered.

Comment: There's another one, it requires you to show popup programatically using JavaScript, basically same thing different package. But you will not find pure CSS solution here.

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: I found only a single ":visible" is needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to change the jQuery Mobile CSS, you can simply override it.

What's causing you problems is that jQuery mobile automatically puts your popup div in a container. If you want to change the width of your popup div you need to target the width of its container.

From jQuery Mobile docs:

> The popup consists of two elements: the screen (...) and the container, which is the popup itself. If your original element had an id attribute, the screen and the container will each receive an id attribute based on it. The screen's id will be suffixed with "-screen", **and the container's id will be suffixed with "-popup"**.

In your case, giving

```
#help-dialog-popup {
    width: 80%;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Tried this and it works. For my case I just simply use .ui-popup-container {  width: 80%;  } to make all my popups 80% wide

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I run into the same problem right now. To create a popup that will look perfect on mobile but not too big for computer screen I use a class like `dialog-medium` below. This way you force the outside container to adjust size and to calculate the right position on screen. You can use `80vw` to resolve the initial request or any percentage you want, but never use a higher percentage.

```
.dialog-medium {
    width:90vw;
    max-width:35em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With browser inspection tool (ex. right-click -> Inspect element) you will find the class that popup uses.
*data-role="popup"* normally uses the *.ui-popup-container*.

So you add into style tag of your page something like the following.

```
.ui-popup-container {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 90vw;
    }
```

In the above example, popup will be 90% of the viewport's size. Assuming that you ve written the  tag.

If you want to have different size on desktop and mobile devices (you should), use the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.ui-popup-container {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 90vw;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
.ui-popup-container {
    height: 60vh;
    width: 60vw;
    }
}
```

In the above example, popup will be 90% of the viewport's size on mobile screens (less than 1001px width) and 60% of viewport's size on big screens (computer)